# Flask - RefferenceError when loading in external JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I am having issues when I am using flask. I re-run flask in vsCode Terminal and in the website (local) I press the " OK " button (specified below), and it returns

`ReferenceError cat is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick`

**base.html**

```
<htmL land="en">
    <head>

        <title>Pub-Quiz</title>
            <!--Required Meta Tags-->
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

            <!-- Bootstrap, Jquery, AJAX, CSS and JS-->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='category.js') }}"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <!--Nav Start-->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-info navbar-dark">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Quiz</a>

                <!--Collapse Button Start-->
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <!--Collapse Button End-->

                <!--Nav Links Start-->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('index')}}"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
                        </li>
                        {% if current_user.is_anonymous %}
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href=" {{ url_for('login') }}"> <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i> Login</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href=" {{ url_for('register') }}"><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i> Register</a>
                        </li>
                        {% else %}
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href=#Quiz><i class="fas fa-clipboard"></i> Quizzes</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href= "{{ url_for('signout')}}"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Sign Out</a>
                        </li>
                        {% endif %}
                    </ul>
                </div> 
                <!--Nav Links End-->
            </nav>
            <!--Nav End-->
        {% block content %} {% endblock %}

        <footer class = "page-footer bg-info">
            <div class ="footer-copyright text-center text-white py-3">@ 2020 Copyright: (something)</div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</htmL>
```

Category.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1 class = "text-center">Choose Your Category</h1>
<div class = "jumbotron">
    <div class = "row justify-content-center">
        <div class = "col-lg-6">
            <form action= "" method="post" novalidate>
                    {{ form.hidden_tag()}}
                <p>
                    {{ form.categories() }}
                </p>
                <div class = "row justify-content-center">
                    <div class ="col-lg-3 mt-lg-4">
                        <button type="submit" name = "submit" class="btn btn-primary mx-auto">Start Quiz</button>
                    </div>   
                </div> 
            </form>
            <button type="button" onclick="cat()">OK</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

category.js

```
function cat()
{
    let opt = document.getElementById("categories").value;
    alert(opt);
}
```

I have tried to move the script from head into the body and even into the  category.html file with no luck. The static file is in the correct directory:  `app -> static -> category.js` Why is this happening? It seems all working in theory for me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you try like this : `<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename=category.js') }}"></script>` in `category.html` and let me know?

Comment: @ngShravil.py I have done that. Still same error

Comment: Are you dealing with some `type` variable?

Comment: @ngShravil.py Yes exactly the same. Its like JS is not being read but its all in the right position dont get it.

Comment: Where are you dealing with `type` variable in JS?

Comment: @ngShravil.py Okay sorry it says "cat" not type.

Comment: Could you just put the function part inside the `script` tag in `category.html` and check?

Comment: @ngShravil.py Like you said in your first comment? I have done that it still raises error. No js seems to work.

Comment: I meant, add `<script>function cat()
{
    let opt = document.getElementById("categories").value;
    alert(opt);
}</script>` to your hrml.

Comment: @ngShravil.py It works but I would like to use an external file since I have a lot of javascript

Comment: @ngShravil.py Check the answer? Having the whol js code in the hmtl file works but I would like an external js file since there is lots and lots of js code

Answer (score 0):

Update your **Category.html** like below:

```html
...
...
{% endblock %}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='cat.js') }}"></script>
```

Or..

```html
...
...
{% endblock %}
<script type="text/javascript">
function cat()
{
    let opt = document.getElementById("categories").value;
    alert(opt);
}
</script>
```

And remove it from **base.html**.

Also when you refreshing the page to see the changes, try removing cache/hard reload or you can try in incognito mode.

Comment: @ngShravill.py Doesnt work. Just to make sure , the in the html button you call ```onclick="cat"``` or ```onclick="cat()"```? Both didnt work for me.

Comment: It should be `cat()`.

Comment: @ngShravill.py Nope still doesnt work. Getting the ReferenceError again

Comment: Where is the `categories` id in your html?

Comment: In my templates folder with every html. So it goes app -> templates -> category.html

Comment: The weird thing is it works when I first start the flask app for the day, then the second run it raises the same errors over and over again. What is causing this? I have cleared my cache.

Comment: Then probably, it must be caching issues. Could you try in incognito mode of your browser?